# how to get information from html page with javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I get information from html page with javascript to php?
I hardcode my userid and password but it cant work...

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var user = ["jack", "james", "lisa"];
    var pass = ["jack123", "james123", "lisa123"];

    function login() {
        var uid = document.getElementById("uid").value;
        var pin = document.getElementById("PIN").value;
            if (uid == user[0] && pin == pass[0] || uid == user[1] && pin == pass[1] || uid == user[2] && pin == pass[2]){
                alert("Log in Successful");
                window.location.href = "Welcom(withdrawal).php" ;
            }
            else{
                alert("Your User ID and PIN do not match!");
                return false;
            }
    }

</script>
```

Form:

```
<section class="right" >
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" >
    <form method="post" onsubmit="login();return false;" >
        <caption id="sidehead">Finger-Print banking</caption>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <label for="uid" >User ID :</label>
            <input class="row2" type="text" tabindex="1" maxlength="20" size="20" name="uid" id="uid">
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>
            <label for="PIN" >PIN :</label>
            <input class="row2" type="password" onkeyup="keyUp(event)" onkeydown="return onlyNumerics(event)" tabindex="2" maxlength="9" size="20" name="PIN" id="PIN" autocomplete="off">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="m">
            <button id="side2">Login</button>
            <button type="reset" id="side1">Reset</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</section>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $userid = $_POST['uid'];

    echo ($userid);
?>
```

I did this but nothing come up,
it says uid is undefined. what happen?

Comment: you prevent your form from submitting with that `return false`, and then you do a `window.location` redirection, which will use a GET to fetch the new page, and also NOT pass in any query parameters since you haven't included any in the url.

Comment: I hope you do not actually want to implement such kind of 'login' system and right now you're just trying out something... That javascript code _including user/pass-combinations_ is sent to the client - this is NOT secure. a password-check should be done server-side (php and database).